# VBA Excel match Copy Paste If Else

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

If Cell.value from Sheet2.Column"A" has no match in Sheet("Civil").Column"A" than copy that cell into Sheets("Sheet2).Column "D"

[Correct Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBmGg.jpg)

Correct result should look like on the attached picture but I have problem with 
 writing a correct code to fill Sheets("Sheet2).Column "D"

```
  Sub NewSearch_A()

 Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, cell1 As Range, n As Integer, m As Integer
Set rng = Sheets("Civil").Range("A2:A1000")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A100")
Set rng3 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C100")
Set rng4 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:D100")

n = 1
m = 1
For Each cell In rng
    n = n + 1
For Each cell1 In rng2
    m = m + 1
        If cell.Value = cell1.Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & m & ":C" & m).Value = Sheets("Civil").Range("B" & n & ":B" & n).Value

         Else

            ' ????????????????????????????????????????????????


        End If
    Next cell1
    m = 1
Next cell
 ActiveSheet.Columns("A:C").AutoFit


End Sub
```

Comment: This may be above your payscale but you should have a look at [Searching values of range X in range Y](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133664/searching-values-of-range-x-in-range-y/133721#133721).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the second loop with a [WorksheetFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
Sub NewSearch_A()
    Dim rw As Long, mtch As Variant, wsc As Worksheet

    Set wsc = Worksheets("Civil")

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            mtch = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, "A").Value2, wsc.Columns("A"), 0)
            If IsError(mtch) Then
                .Cells(rw, "D") = .Cells(rw, "A").Value2
            Else
                .Cells(rw, "C") = wsc.Cells(mtch, "B").Value2
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you @Jeeped  for the great lesson in VBA coding!

Comment: Sometimes a nested loop is necessary. When it is, use `Exit For` once you reach your goal so that you do not continue to examine any more rows. The inner loop will be exited and the outer loop will resume where it left off.